# NSNumber numberFromString not placed decimals

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

I am trying to convert NSString to NSNumber and it seems to create a decimal point issue here.

```
NSString *str = @"515.51515";

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:str];
NSLog(@"Number here:%@",myNumber);
[f release];
```

& result print is
2015-03-01 08:09:28.353 myApp [57376:2086924] Number here: **515.5151499999999**

Actual debug log picture here

[image]

but actually it should be **515.51515** rather **515.5151499999999**.

I tried all comibination with f.usesSignificantDigits & f.maximumFractionDigits =10 but no luck.
please let me know How to fix this?

Comment: What you are seeing is correct. Floating point numbers are rarely exact.

Comment: if you want to see the result formatted you may need to use the formatter explicitly on a `double`, like e.g. `%.6f` or so.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use NSDecimalNumber? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/

Comment: This is a dupe 100 times over, but I'm too lazy to look one up right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMaddy is correct, floating point numbers will be a bit off.

Since an NSDecimalNumber is an NSNumber you can use:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"515.51515"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use construction:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[str floatValue]];
```

I think it should work correctly.

Comment: Don't "think" it "should" work correctly. Try it and be sure. It's unlikely this answer will give a different result for the string posted in the question.

Comment: For me it don't really work, i get 515.5151 without the last 5(?). More interesting is why this would work. If you change numberWithFloat to numberWithDouble it will again fail since the higher precision. Could also be that you get different results on 64 vs 32 bit architecture since CGFloat is typed to a double on 64 and a float on 32.

Comment: I tried with [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[str floatValue]]; & [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[str doubleValue]]; both are given different results